# What is a reasonable course to convert a novel from latex to epub/azw?

Tags: ebook, epub, xhtml

I need to convert a novel (NO math, but lots of citations and direct speech) from current PDF/printed paper to high-quality epub/azw4 to publish as eBook.

Current layout is based on `memoir` and `quotmark`.

I know I can use `htlatex` to produce a reasonable output, but that is not really satisfactory because it produces a single `.html` file with little control over chapters that do not behave "as expected" (i.e.: start a chapter at top of page and not like a "continuous ribbon").

I would like to have a behavior similar to standard `Kindle Create` output (I tried going the latex->docx->KindleCreate way, but it messes badly with direct speech and "maiuscoletto" I use heavily (using Italian language might add noise to process as MSWord has "localized" Style names possibly unknown to other tools).

Can someone suggest a viable alternative?

I did not find a suitable answer perusing similar questions.

Comment: Acording to https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GUGQ4WDZ92F733GC#trouble your best choice is possibly PdfLaTeX (non reflowable PDF) to Complex Textbook but the price is a more limited range of hardware (However it seems to be the majority of current reader applications) best way is to use the preview functionality

Comment: I have an epub output format on my latex-to-xyz code, which can be found at https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet  It is somewhat experimental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tex4ebook](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex4ebook?lang=en) can produce `ePub`, `ePub3` and `mobi` formats from LaTeX sources. It uses `tex4ht` (the same system as `htlatex` uses) for the LaTeX to HTML conversion. The HTML files are then processed and packed to produce the requested output. It needs the `kindlegen` command installed for the `mobi` output.

Basic usage:

```
tex4ebook -f epub3 filename.tex
```

You may want to add some custom metadata, cover image or a nice CSS. It can be added using a configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}   
\CoverMetadata{cover.png}
\Configure{AddCss}{blitz-lite.css}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Save the file as `myconfig.cfg` and require it in `tex4ebook` using the following command:

```
tex4ebook -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

The config file adds a cover image named `conver.png` (it must exist in the current directory) and the CSS file provided by [The Blitz Framework](https://github.com/FriendsOfEpub/Blitz). You may add how many CSS files you want using the `\Configure{AddCss}`

BTW, even `htlatex` can produce separate HTML files for each chapter:

```
htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,2"
```

The number in the last parameter specifies at which sectioning levels should be the files partitioned, there are four possible levels (up to `\subsection` I think). It produces some navigation in each file, which is not that useful in ebooks. `tex4ebook` removes the navigation, so it is still preferable to use it instead of `htlatex`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be exactly what I need. I will need to tweak a bit `\frontmatter` and insert a few images. Can You suggest the right style to get a properly formatted e-book? Note: my volume is quite large (>700 pages) and divided in three `\part`; what is the right way to put cover/description/author info in an e-book?

Comment: @ZioByte I've updated my answer. The author and title should be included automatically from the `\title` and `\author` commands.

Comment: I'm having problems with images (in the text, not cover; inserted using `\includegraphics`): they disappear from tex4ebook completely (I didn't find *any* reference to the files in logs). Can You divine what's happening or should I issue another Question?

Comment: @ZioByte do you use the image extensions in `\includedraphics`? if not, you may need to add the `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.svg,.png,.jpg,.pdf}` command to the configuration file. It it doesn't help, it would be best to post a new question.